# Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox SOlution Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a problem with Sharepoint Server 2010 sandbox solution. When I write

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://win-5g8rm9qpjrp");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
```

these 2 lines of code. I have an error like this. Please help me. Thanks

```
Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

[SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.]

 Server stack trace: 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAppDomain.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxyForShim.ExecuteInternal(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext) 

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.ExecuteDelegate.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String currentAffinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodePoolableProcessConnection.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext) 

 Exception rethrown at [1]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

[InvalidOperationException: Sandboxed code solution has leaked these IDisposable objects: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ]

 Server stack trace: 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Subset.Shim.DisposableObjectsMonitor.CleanupRemoteDisposableObjects() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Subset.Shim.DisposableObjectsMonitor.Dispose() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.ExecuteWrapper(SPUserCodeWrapper wrapper, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink) 

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.CodeToExecuteWrapper.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find the answer. It is too easy.

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://win-5g8rm9qpjrp"))
{
     using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
     {
       //Codes related about the SPSite

     }

}
```