# SharePoint2010:Getting Files From Library in Sandbox

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to get Files from Shared Library in Sandbox solutions. When I try these code, it does not work.

string documentLibrary = "Shared Documents";
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://win-5g8rm9qpjrp");

Is there any other way or any kind of answer for getting documents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured your Visual Studio 2010 project trust level is set to "Deploy as sandboxed solution"? This is from the options you get when you first setup your project.

When you say "it does not work". What is happening? Is there an error?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. But other sandbox solutions is working. When I deploy these codes in sharepoint page i had an error. You can check this error my other post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879423/sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution-error